# How to send different param and value randomly to request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, parameterization

I have 5 APIs which uses different form of ids like **Uid, Sid** and **Did** .
With each request any one from those three is required.
List of **Uid, Sid** and **Did** are stored in separate CSV file.
My req samples looks like

```
http://Host:port/Users?me=checkUser&Uid=U_User1
http://Host:port/Users?me=checkUser&Sid=S_12
http://Host:port/Users?me=checkUser&Did=D_90101

http://Host:port/AddrUsers?me=checkUser&Uid=U_User1
http://Host:port/AddrUsers?me=checkUser&Sid=S_12
http://Host:port/AddrUsers?me=checkUser&Did=D_90101
```

Pulling Uid, Sid and Did from CSV randomly is doable but expected is

```
http://Host:port/Users?me=checkUser&Uid=${UID} or Sid=${SID} or Did=${DID} 
http://Host:port/AddrUsers?me=checkUser&Uid=${UID} or Sid=${SID} or Did=${DID}
```

**So without creating set of three for each APIs I want to pass Param name and Ids to single request** [Ignore OR that just to differentiate param. Each request will only have one Id from Uid, Sid, Did]

I am aware about using CSV values through **Uid = ${UID}** in *http request* parameters section

Right now I am using 3 cvs and 3 version of same APIs to call the requests with **Uids, Sids and Dids**

But is it possible to have one CSV having all the Ids (mix of ids) and send those values to each requests randomly?

Comment: You can try using [bzm-Random Data Set Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-the-random-csv-data-set-config-plugin-on-jmeter). This provides a capability to parameterize your Test Plan from a CSV file in random order of records.

Comment: @raj Okay.. Values we can take randomly from CVS but, how to change param name with request randomly instead of calling them three time?

Answer (score 0):

So you should create your bzm-Random CSV set like:

```
ID,Value //CSV header
UID,UidValue1
SID,SidValue1
DID,DidValue1
UID,UidValue2
SID,SidValue2
DID,DidValue3 and so on...
```

Under the bzm-Random set **check** the **"Random Order" & "First Line is CSV Header"**

and now your URL would be like:

```
http://Host:port/Users?me=checkUser&${ID}=${Value}
```

This way you will be able to iterate the values using single request.

Comment: Great buddy. I'll try this.. TIA